# Merging two dataframe with dplyr left join?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, left-join

I have two data frames,  `competitor_sheet` and `left_join_prototype`, which I'll call df1 and df2, respectively, df1 and df2 each contain information on genes and disease IDs, and look like this:

df1:

| HUGO_symbol | MeSH_ID |
| --- | --- |
| P53 | D000310 |
| A1BG | D0002277 |
| ZZZ3 | D000230 |

df2:

| Gene.Name | Parent.MeSH.ID | Child.MeSH.ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P53 | D000310 | D015675, D006676 |
| HGA2 | D031031 | D002277 |
| ZZZ3 | D001163, D000230 | D003451 |

As you can see, df2 may contain multiple IDs in both the Parent and Child MeSH ID's. Essentially, what I want to do is left join any rows from df2 to df1  if any of the MeSH ID's in either the child or parent correspond to MeSH ID's in the df1, but only if the Gene.Name = HUGO_symbol, the final product should look like this:

| HUGO_symbol | MeSH_ID | Gene.Name | Parent.Mesh.ID | Child.MeSH.ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P53 | D000310 | P53 | D000310 | D015675, D006676 |
| ZZZ3 | D000230 | ZZZ3 | D001163, D00230 | D003451 |

I've tried something using dplyr that looks something like this:

`proto <- left_join(df1,df2, by = c("MeSH_ID"="Parent.MeSH.ID", "HUGO_Symbol"="Gene.Name", "MeSH_ID2"="Child.MeSH.ID"))` where `proto` would be the new table but I have a feeling this is wrong.

As always, any help is hugely appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that a left_join looks for exact matches and there is nothing like "match this or that". Hence, to achieve your desired result you could

1. unite `Parent.MeSH.ID` and `Child.MeSH.ID` into a new column `MeSH_ID`
2. split the united columns in separate IDs using e.g. `tidyr::separate_rows`. Doing so makes it possible to join the df's by ID.
3. Use an `semi_join` to filter out rows in df1 with matches in the newly created df3, finally do a `left_join` to add the columns from df3. Or if doesn't matter to keep both `HUGO_symbol` and `Gene.Name` you could achieve both steps with an `inner_join`.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
       HUGO_symbol = c("P53", "A1BG", "ZZZ3"),
           MeSH_ID = c("D000310", "D0002277", "D000230")
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
         Gene.Name = c("P53", "HGA2", "ZZZ3"),
    Parent.MeSH.ID = c("D000310", "D031031", "D001163, D000230"),
     Child.MeSH.ID = c("D015675, D006676", "D002277", "D003451")
)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df3 <- df2 %>%
  unite("MeSH_ID", Parent.MeSH.ID, Child.MeSH.ID, sep = ", ", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  separate_rows(MeSH_ID, sep = ", ")

semi_join(df1, df3, by = c("HUGO_symbol" = "Gene.Name", "MeSH_ID")) %>% 
  left_join(df3)
#> Joining, by = "MeSH_ID"
#>   HUGO_symbol MeSH_ID Gene.Name   Parent.MeSH.ID    Child.MeSH.ID
#> 1         P53 D000310       P53          D000310 D015675, D006676
#> 2        ZZZ3 D000230      ZZZ3 D001163, D000230          D003451
```